# Explanation on unpacking a list with itertools.product

Tags: python, args, iterable-unpacking

I cant seem to wrap my head around how unpacking (*) along with itertools.product() is working with the example below.

```
for x in product(["ghi","abc"]):
    print(x)
```

output:

```
('ghi',)
('abc',)
```

And using *

```
for x in product(*["ghi","abc"]):
    print(x)
```

output:

```
('g', 'a')
('g', 'b')
('g', 'c')
('h', 'a')
('h', 'b')
('h', 'c')
('i', 'a')
('i', 'b')
('i', 'c')
```

How was this output generated? I know product() usually generates the combinations given the number of 'repeat'.  As for above, repeat is default to 1.  How come a ('a','g') wasnt generated?

I guess what did `*["ghi","abc"]` actually produce to the `product()` function?  I mean I see what the outcome is but I just cant seem to get how it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unpack the arguments to `product` it would be the same as manual entering each element from the list as a argument. That is:

`product(*[a, b]) == product(a, b)`

So what your really doing is passing each string in the list into `product()`. Python is simply doing this behind the scenes for you.

The reason `('a', 'g')` didn't appear in the results is simply because of how product works. [The official documentation  of product does a good job of explaining how exactly it works](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.
>
> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product tuples are emitted in sorted order.
>
> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number of repetitions with the optional *repeat* keyword argument. For example, `product(A, repeat=4)` means the same as `product(A, A, A, A)`.
>
> This function is roughly equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory:
>
> ```
> def product(*args, repeat=1):
>     # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
>     # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
>     pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
>     result = [[]]
>     for pool in pools:
>         result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
>     for prod in result:
>         yield tuple(prod)
> ```

Comment: The explanation you provided and the snippet of how product work was really helpful.  I initially thought most of the work was with the unpacking, but turns out its really all in the product function. Thanks.

Comment: @user1179317 Glad I help :-)